# Get-ChildItem objects look identical but vary on absolute vs relative path when compared

Tags: powershell

Different usages of `Get-ChildItem` produce `System.IO.FileInfo` objects that look identical, but don't compare.

```
$a = (Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\Boot\Fonts)[0]
$b = (Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\Boot\Fonts\*)[0]
compare $a $b
```

Produces

```
InputObject                        SideIndicator
-----------                        -------------
C:\Windows\Boot\Fonts\chs_boot.ttf =>
chs_boot.ttf                       <=
```

But viewing `$a` and `$b` using `select *` does not show up the relative vs absolute path difference in the `System.IO.FileInfo` objects.

Is there any way to differentiate between $a and $b other than using `Compare-Object`?

Comment: `$a.ToString()` and `$b.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's simple. I was expecting property differences, must be in hidden properties. I didn't find anything obvious the `PSObject` property, but now noticed that `$a.PSObject` and `$b.PSObject` also show the difference in their `BaseObject` property.

Comment: @DavidGibson You're recursively seeing the same thing. `$b.psobject.BaseObject.psobject.BaseObject` is a reference to `$b.psobject.BaseObject` is a reference to `$b` ;)

Comment: As they are both of type System.IO.FileSystemInfo I'm curious as to how they are producing different ToString() results.

Comment: @PetSerAl I now understand why and where Cmdlets that use the `Param ([string[]] $Path)` were failing to handle the output of `Get-ChildItem` for some files. The `[string[]]` typecasts arguments by calling `ToString()`, so by the time code inside the Cmdlet sees the `$Path`, relative paths have been truncated.